# How to run a program at a specific time and date but only on logon

Tags: windows

I need to be able to launch a web page at login for the 3rd Monday of each month. Key words there are "at login" and “3rd Monday of each month”. I seem to be able to do one or the other…but, not both. I'm open to any suggestions, scripts, and ideas you might have.

I have tried the following: Group Policy – I found nothing that can control the "when". I can do at login and/or log out but not on the 3rd Monday of each month. Scheduled Tasks – This is the one where it's one or the other.

I can do a scheduled time/date or at login…but not both. If I add both options as "triggers"…it literally treats them separately and thus launches when either criterion has been met. I've reviewed various scripts but nothing close to what I’m trying to accomplish.

I am asking everyone, so I thought I would throw you in. thanks.

Comment: My experience is also that you can do one or the other.  An alternative is to write a script, and trigger the script on login.  The first thing that the script does is to test if it's the 3rd Monday of the month...

Comment: You could do this indirectly. Create one task that will call a batch file the 3rd Monday of each month. Create another task that will call a different batch file at login. In the batch files, you could create create arbritary files somewhere on your computer and have a third batch file check to see if they both exist, then execute the relevant code. Clumsy, but it could work. Christopher Hostage has a better solution - use your login script, which you could use a GPO to configure or place in startup, and test if it is the 3rd monday. You can put this in an if- and then execute.

Comment: That's how I'd handle it too... with a script.... batch script using PowerShell, VBS or maybe even pure batch if it can handling confirming it's the 3rd Monday of the month. I assume you would only want this to launch once at logon on this day or at every logon on this day for ever user? You'd need to add more logic to keep track that it's been executed once per user per machine or whatever if you only want it run once.